# How to make video.js and videoJSIMA work in react (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, video.js

I need to create a video player in NextJS12. I decided to use the video.js framework and videojs ima for this.

I have the following component in nextJS:

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';

import "videojs-ima";
import "videojs-contrib-ads";

import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

export const ThorPlayer = ({ ima, ...props }) => {

  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { options, onReady } = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        console.log(ima);
        onReady && onReady(player);
      });
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources); 
      player.ima(ima);
    }
  }, [options, videoRef]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <div ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ThorPlayer;
```

I'm calling it that on my page:

```
 <ThorPlayer 
                    ima={{ 
                        adTagUrl: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=/21775744923/external/single_ad_samples&sz=640x480&cust_params=sample_ct%3Dlinear&ciu_szs=300x250%2C728x90&gdfp_req=1&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator="' 
                    }}
                    options={thorPlayerOptions} 
                    onReady={onThorPlayerReady}
                />
```

The video works normally but for some reason the IMA AD doesn't work... can anyone help me ?

All I need is to get AD to work.

Comment: I think the ad tag works only once. After that you need another tag

Comment: in fact, it's not working even once